# How to dry code with each in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here what I have:

```
_visits = _visits.select { |v| v.webmaster == options[:webmaster] } if options[:webmaster]
_visits = _visits.select { |v| v.country_code == options[:country_code] } if options[:country_code]
_visits = _visits.select { |v| v.created_at > options[:period].first && v.created_at < options[:period].last } if options[:period]

_leads = _leads.select { |l| l.webmaster == options[:webmaster] } if options[:webmaster]
_leads = _leads.select { |l| l.country_code == options[:country_code] } if options[:country_code]
_leads = _leads.select { |l| l.created_at > options[:period].first && l.created_at < options[:period].last } if options[:period]
```

As you see, the code it actually the same. So I've tried:

```
[ _visits, _leads ].each do |e|
  e = e.select { |_e| _e.webmaster == options[:webmaster] } if options[:webmaster]
  e = e.select { |_e| _e.country_code == options[:country_code] } if options[:country_code]
  e = e.select { |_e| _e.created_at > options[:period].first && _e.created_at < options[:period].last } if options[:period]
end
```

And it didn't work thus ruby passes-by-value. Any workaround here?

Comment: serious refactoring required. make sure you have tests first.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe it's because it's late and I'm tired, but you seem to be overwriting the variable you're calling… and the conditional tests end up in either true or false, which isn't really how you'd normally use `select`. I suggest you clarify what you *aim* is and post it along with the question.

Comment: Compare the use of [`select` in the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) with `[1,2,3,4,5].select { |num| true }` and `[1,2,3,4,5].select { |num| false }` and perhaps you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @iain I need to filter visits and leads with options given, `[1,2,3,4,5].select { |num| num == 3 }` is what I do

Comment: Ah, got you. It is late and I *am* tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could work

```
_visits, _leads = [ _visits, _leads ].map do |e|
  e = e.select { |_e| _e.webmaster == options[:webmaster] } if options[:webmaster]
  e = e.select { |_e| _e.country_code == options[:country_code] } if options[:country_code]
  e.select { |_e| _e.created_at > options[:period].first && _e.created_at < options[:period].last } if options[:period]
end
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test this at all, but the code as the current answer has it now (through no fault of their own, they were just answering the question you asked) - as well as your original code -  would iterate through both your leads and your visits three times.  This may be even less performant, but consider doing something like this:

```
_visits, _leads = [_vists, _leads].map do |e|
  e.select do |elem|
    (options[:webmaster] ? elem.webmaster == options[:webmaster] : true)
    && (options[:country_code] ? elem.country_code == options[:country_code] : true)
    && (options[:period] ? _e.created_at > options[:period].first && _e.created_at < options[:period].last : true)
  end
end
```

To clean it up and avoid looking things up in your options hash a large amount of times(no idea how many checks it would be making or how expensive it is) you could do this.

```
webmaster    = options[:webmaster]
country_code = options[:country_code]
period       = options[:period]

_visits, _leads = [_vists, _leads].map do |e|
  e.select do |elem|
    (webmaster ? elem.webmaster == webmaster : true)
    && (country_code ? elem.country_code == country_code : true)
    && (period ? _e.created_at > period.first && _e.created_at < period.last : true)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you don't need to retain the original composition of _visits and _leads you can clean it all up by using select!.